# "Can't write to SD card" error message when trying to read from SD card

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery

I've found from online that the "Can't write to SD card" error message often means the card is busted. I would back up everything into my OneDrive, but it doesn't even read anymore. I still get the same message every 10 seconds, but nothing shows up in my gallery. According to troubleshooting, the card isn't connected or is broken.

So, is there something I can do to still recover all the stuff? Should I try connecting the card to my PC, if I find my SD adapter?

If needed, I got a Samsung Galaxy A51 with a 64 GB SD.

Comment: Which message do you get every 10 seconds? Was the sd-card initialized as portable or adopted internal storage?

Comment: I get the message that I quoted in the title and it's a portable storage. And this thing ate 40% of my battery in 20 minutes.

Comment: Then try a USB SD-card adapter and check it on your PC. SD-cards often go into read-only mode when they detect severe defects in their flash chip.

Comment: I'm answering quite late, but I got it sorted. The notification I talked about before was caused by the card connecting and disconnecting. That obviously makes it impossible to read anything from it. I somehow got it stable and it stayed connected, meaning that everything is copied now.

Comment: So the reason was an unstable physical connection between card and reader?

Comment: Well that's only the reason why it spammed me the notification and I couldn't read anything from it properly. The card is actually almost busted, but it's all backed up now. Idk why the connection became stable again or why it wasn't like that before, but it doesn't really matter, I guess.